# maximum volume of a box with perimeter and area given

Tags: rounding, volume, area, maximize

Here's the link to the question..

http://www.codechef.com/problems/J7

I figured out that 2 edges have to be equal in order to give the maximum volume, and then used x, x, a*x as the lengths of the three edges to write the equations -

4*x + 4*x + 4*a*x = P (perimeter) and,

2*x^2 + 4*(a*x *x) = S (total area of the box)

so from the first equation I got x in terms of P and a, and then substituted it in the second equation and then got a quadratic equation with the unknown being a. and then I used the greater root of a and got x.
But this method seems to be giving the wrong answer! :|
I know that there isn't any logical error in this. Maybe some formatting error?

Here's the main code that I've written :

```
{  

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TheBestBox box = new TheBestBox();

        reader = box.new InputReader(System.in);
        writer = box.new OutputWriter(System.out);

        getAttributes();

        writer.flush();

        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void getAttributes()
    {
        t = reader.nextInt(); // t is the number of test cases in the question

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            p = reader.nextInt(); // p is the perimeter given as input
            area = reader.nextInt(); // area of the whole sheet, given as input

            a = findRoot(); // the fraction by which the third side differs by the first two
            side = (double) p / (4 * (2 + a)); // length of the first and the second sides (equal)

            height = a * side; // assuming that the base is a square, the height has to be the side which differs from the other two

            // writer.println(side * side * height);

            // System.out.printf("%.2f\n", (side * side * height));

            writer.println(String.format("%.2f", (side * side * height))); // just printing out the final answer
        }
    }

    public static double findRoot() // the method to find the 2 possible fractions by which the height can differ from the other two sides and return the bigger one of them
    {
        double a32, b, discriminant, root1, root2;

        a32 = 32 * area - p * p;
        b = 32 * area - 2 * p * p;

        discriminant = Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * 8 * area * a32);

        double temp;

        temp = 2 * 8 * area;

        root1 = (- b + discriminant) / temp; 
        root2 = (- b - discriminant) / temp;

        return Math.max(root1, root2);
    }
}
```

could someone please help me out with this? Thank You. :)

Comment: Please clean up your question and also include the source code you have authored.  Stack Overflow is primarily for coding questions, although you can certainly ask your question here.

Comment: ohk..I did as much as I could..
and I've also added the source code!
it's not the whole code. just the variable declaration and the input,output classes aren't included.

Comment: isn't there anyone who can help me out with this??

Answer (score 1):

I also got stuck in this question and realized that can be done by making equation of V(volume) in terms of one side say 'l' and using differentiation to find maximum volume in terms of any one side 'l'.

So, equations are like this :-

```
P = 4(l+b+h); 
S = 2(l*b+b*h+l*h); 
V = l*b*h;
```

so equation in l for V = (l^3) - (l^2)*P/4 + l*S/2 -------equ(1)

After differentiation we get:-

```
 d(V)/d(l) = 3*(l^2) - l*P/2 + S/2;
```

to get max V we need to equate above equation to zero(0) and get the value of l.
So, solutions to a quadratic equation will be:-

```
l = ( P + sqrt((P^2)-24S) ) / 24;
```

so substitute this l in equation(1) to get max volume.